# Editing a text file - deleting unnecessary characters

Tags: php, file, text, edit, strlen

I am working in PHP and I have no idea how can I make loop and delete all signs >200 in each `:86:` data block (after `:86:` and before `:61:`) in a text file.

The text file looks like below:

```
:86:
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here 
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here

:61:20010301034578997d Some text not interested here doesn't matter

:86:
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here
I want to leave only 200 signs here

:61:20010301034578997d Some text not interested here doesn't matter
```

and so on

Please help me ;)

Comment: What have you tried or attempted so far ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two steps:

first, find all the parts between :86: and :61: - for this i usualy use a regex pattern with a lookbehind `(?<=)` and lookahead `(?=)`, like this:

```
// your source text
$source = ':86: I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here

:61:20010301034578997d Some text not interested here doesnt matter

:86: I xwant to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here I want to leave only 200 signs here

:61:20010301034578997d Some text not interested here doesnt matter and so on Please help me ;)';


// search for the parts between :86: and :61:
preg_match_all('/(?<=:86:)(.*?)(?=:61:)/is',$source,$matches);
```

keep in mind that your text has a new line before the :61: - this new line will also be deleted, as it is a character and beyond the 200 character threshold

now you have an array with all the matches (`$matches`) - you can use that to replace it with cropped versions of the text.

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    $source = str_replace(':86:' . $match . ':61:',':86:' . substr($match,0,200) . ':61:',$source);
}
```

As you can see, i still use the :86: & :61: while replacing the text - this is because the same text that was found between these two could also occur somewhere else, and we want to only replace it between :86: and :61:

Comment: Brilliant answer it is really working ;) Thank you very much dear friend ;)